# JS regex matching whole words with hyphen In dataTables

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

Not sure if this is best posted here or on the JQ dataTables forum. I'll try here.

Doing exact regex matching on columns in a dataTable and have two cases one works great but the second not so good!

**CASE 1**
Column data

```
Joe    
Bob    
Sue   
Bobby    
Joey
```

So then I want all the rows that have Joe, Bob, Sue and not Bobby and Joey.

MY regex looks like this;

```
 \b(Joe|Bob|Sue)\b
```

And it works great.  I see filtered rows for the three names and not Bobby and Joey.
I use the pipe separated list because I also store the filter list in URL parameter so the filtered version can be book marked.

Now my problem case:
**CASE 2**
Column data

```
Joe    
Bob    
Sue   
Bobby    
Joey
Ann
Jo-Ann
```

In this case I want Bob Sue and Ann rows.

Using this regex

```
\b(Bob|Sue|Ann)\b
```

Gets the rows I want but also gets the Jo-Ann Rows, I assume because the - is being treated as a boundary between words.

Play around with [\w-] but can't seem to get it work on a pipe separated list.
Below is the fiddle.

http://refiddle.co/1v1j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a **DIY** boundary.

Using either a capture or non-capturing group we can assert that the start of the string or a space character precedes while asserting that a space character or the end of the string follows your grouped pattern.

```
(?:^| )(Bob|Sue|Ann)(?: |$)
```

You could also use a negated character class if you prefer. On the right side of the alternation operator, instead of matching a space character in the above regular expression, we match a character that is not a hyphen or a word character, which is closer to the intent of expanding the word boundary and do the same for the group that follows.

```
(?:^|[^-\w])(Bob|Sue|Ann)(?:[^-\w]|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

line feed could be applied in your case

```
/\s*(Bob|Joe|Ann)\s*\n/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:Bob|Sue|Ann)$
```

You can apply anchors as well.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/3